# Looking for v6 or VB.net encryption for double encryption

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I would like to encrypt a string with keyA then encrypt the result with keyB then decrypt that result with keyA and finally retrieve original string with keyB.

I am using VB6 and/or VB.net

Comment: solutions for VB.NET are not interchangeable with VB6

Answer (score 1):

Use CTR mode encryption such as the one used in [Bouncy Castle for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376118/589259). CTR uses XOR as last step, and XOR is commutative.

Comment: Note that I won't go into the details why you want to do such a thing, double encryption is not very useful most of the time (at least not for data, you could however encrypt a data key multiple times).