# AES CTR decryption in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

I've been given the task of decrypting some data in C# that was originally encrypted using PHP.  Below is the PHP code

```
$opts = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
$res = openssl_decrypt($raw, 'aes-256-ctr', $keyhash, $opts, base64_decode($iv));
```

$raw is a byte array with a length of 312, $keyhash is 32 bytes and $iv is 16 bytes.

My problem is when I duplicate this code in C# I receive the following CryptographicException -
**The input data is not a complete block.**

Not being a crypto guy, I've tried many, many C# examples to try to get this to work, but pretty much always end up with the same error.  This is one sample of the C# code I've tried.

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an AesManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;

    }
```

I've implemented the code in PHP and it works fine.  I've also checked all the input byte arrays and they all exactly the same for both PHP and C#.  In desperation I even implemented this in Java and again it works no problem.

```
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyHash, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/PKCS5PADDING");


        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);  
        byte [] original = cipher.doFinal(encData);
        String plaintext = new String(original);
```

So what's up with the C# code and how can I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first guess would be the padding. If I remember correctly, there was a differecne in c# and java's implementations ... if I only could remember exactly ... , but I think it's worthwhile researching in that direction.

Comment: CTR mode is not implemented in .NET. You can read this question for some inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6374437/5311735

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use AES in CTR mode in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374437/can-i-use-aes-in-ctr-mode-in-net)

Comment: @Fildor CTR mode does **not** use padding.

Comment: @zaph exactly. That is the problem.

Comment: @Fildor It is not a padding "differecne in c# and java's implementations" since CTR mode does not use padding in either/any.

Comment: @zaph yes. Exactly. See evk's comment.

Answer (score 3):

OK.  This is a duplicate question which has already been answered.  I just missed the easy answer, which is here - [Aes128CounterMode.cs](https://gist.github.com/hanswolff/8809275). And this code will generate the correct result -

```
byte[] plainText = new byte[encData.Length];
Aes128CounterMode am = new Aes128CounterMode(iv); 
ICryptoTransform ict = am.CreateEncryptor(keyHash, null);
ict.TransformBlock(encData, 0, encData.Length, plainText, 0);
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
```

Comment: What changes should I do to achieve AES 256 ?

Comment: AES 256 is included in the standard .Net crypto libraries.  You should just be able to Google an answer easily enough!

Comment: Yes, I am looking AES 256 + CTR mode