# Crypto algorithm nodejs and c#

Tags: c#, node.js

My nodejs application is using crypto library to encrypt stream below

```js
var gfsStream = gfs.createWriteStream(options)
var rs = new BufferReadable()
var encrypt = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', 'my password')
rs.pipe(encrypt).pipe(gfsStream)
```

How to decrypt in c# code?
Thank you.

Comment: See [Can I use AES in CTR mode in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6374437/982149)

Comment: I try that before but didn't work